# How to get the formatted value of a number for a cell in Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I wanted to get the value of a Numeric cell as a simple string.

Suppose there the type of cell is numeric with value `90%`.
Now I cannot use `cell.getStringCellValue()` as it will throw exception.
I also cannot use `cell.getNumericCellValue()` as it will return me `.9` and not `90%`.

I want to store in db which is of type varchar2, so I want the value in string only.

I cannot change the cell type in `xls` as its the end user job, I have to handle this in code itself.

Also formatter does't work well as there could be different cell types in the xls...dd:mm,dd:mm:ss,formula etc.

All I want is that whatever the cell type is I need to get its value as simple String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force the value to be returned as a String using the methods below

```
HSSFDataFormatter hdf = new HSSFDataFormatter();
System.out.println (hdf.formatCellValue(mycell));
```

will return "90%"

The API for this method is at http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29

This works directly even with an HSSFCell

it worked for me even when my Cell is an HSSFCell

i've also tried this cast - which works.

```
HSSFCell cell1 = (HSSFCell) row1.getCell(2);

HSSFDataFormatter hdf = new HSSFDataFormatter();
System.out.println ("formatted "+ hdf.formatCellValue(cell1));
```

Comment: HSSFDataFormatter hdf = new HSSFDataFormatter();
System.out.println (hdf.formatCellValue(mycell));
In my case the "myCell" argument is of type HSSFCell but hdf.formatCellValue(mycell) take "mycell" as a type of Cell. I tried typecasting it to Cell but it throws an exception:java.lang.ClassCastException.....actually my code is written using HSSF API...

Comment: I tried with HSSF cell ...It works but when i run as a standalone java class with java 1.6....I have my application on portal 6.1 where i have to use java 1.5...It throws exception there..

Comment: @user371238: I've tried this with standalone 1.5 and 1.6. do you have the latest poi libraries in server web-inf/lib?

Comment: tried 3.6...still getting the same error=java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Comment: can you post the whole stacktrace as an Edit to your original question?

Comment: i can run on standalone java class with 1.5 also ..but its not running on portal server 6.1 which has 1.5...with 3.6 jar

Comment: Does not work. `1578390016427` is returns something like : `1.57839E+12`

Comment: @PranjalCholadhara: your query is resolved at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431561/apache-poi-dataformatter-returns-scientific-notation

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
cell.getRichStringCellValue ().getString();
```

[Have a look at this example](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/41-apache-poi-reading-excel-sheet-using-java-2.html)
[Here is Doc](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html)

Comment: cell.getRichStringCellValue ().getString();  It Didn,t work...Error:-lang.NoSuchMethodError  I am using poi 3.6 jar

Comment: @user371238  Have you checked the example's code , Try with older version of jar. document shows the method and it is there.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is using current `apache poi` versions of 2021. Now [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) can be used for `XSSF` (Office Open XML `*.xlsx`) as well as for `HSSF` (BIFF `*.xls`) formats. It should be used together with [FormulaEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html) to get values from formula cells too.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ReadExcel {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Excel.xlsx"));
  //Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Excel.xls"));

  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(java.util.Locale.US);
  FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

  String cellValue = "";

  for (Sheet sheet: workbook) {
   System.out.println(sheet.getSheetName());
   for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {

     cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator);
     System.out.println(cell.getAddress() + ":" + cellValue);
     // do something with cellValue

    }
   }
  }
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```